# how to use c# snippet prop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c#-express-2010

Just got to know about C# snippet. But i am unable to use them in my code.
Help me out please, I am messed up with get set and how they work.

Here is my test class named "myclass"

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

{
    class myclass
    {
        public string getmessage(string givenName)
        {
            return "HB "+givenName;
        }

        private string bmessage;

        public string MyProperty
        {
            get { return bmessage; }
            set { bmessage = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

In button code from my form. I am unable to use these get set.
It ll be great if someone clears that how can i use these get set.
Moreover what is "MyProperty" here? I know it is not a method. What is its purpose? Thanks

Comment: This looks like a c# 101 question, not anything to do with Snippets. You should probably go read up on [C# Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)?  What does your question have to do with snippets?

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s10p5.html check this link. It is adding prob through snippet. You may leave. if it is making any sense.

Comment: @BradChristie Your comment was very helpful. I would have accepted it, if u had putted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Snippets itself are not executable statements. But are short-cuts that help you in writing executable statements.

For e.g.

If we write `prop` and press enter, it will give you a auto-generated property. You just have to change Datatype and Property Name.

Similarly `propfull` will give a property with get and set parts.

In your case `MyProperty` is the Property Name and string is the DataType. `bmessage` is the backing field for your property.

Comment: +1 for `propfull`, so many years I have been using VS, I never noticed it.

Comment: The issue is, How will i use those get set function in my program? I'm unable to call them and use them with myclass object.

Comment: When you want to use `MyProperty` its value will be retrieved from `bmessage`. Similary while assigning, value will be residing in `bmessage`  You don't have to do anything.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal The first comment on my question was from where i got it cleared. That was just a formal thank for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The properties of a class are set and retrieved by using set/get methods. Basically these are also methods.

```
namespace BusinessObjects
{
public class class_BusinessObjects
{
    int StusentId;      
        string StudentName;        

    public class_BusinessObjects ()
    {       
        StusentId = 0;
        StudentName = string.Empty;
    }

    public int StusentId
        {
                get
        {  
            return Id;
                }
                set
                {
                    Id = value;
                }
        }       

        public string StudentName
        {
                get
                {
                    return Name;
                }
                set
                {
                    Name = value;
                }
        }        
}
}


using BusinessObjects;
namespace MyModel
{
public class A
{
    public class_BusinessObjects Dispaly(int id, string name)
        {
        class_BusinessObjects obj = new class_BusinessObjects();
        obj.StusentId = id;
        obj.StudentName = name;
        return obj;
    }
}
}
```